# Issue with array, foreach transaction

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a array, I am trying to iterate through in PHP;

https://pastebin.com/he4bD4T0 *I have had to shorten it because its so long*

I am currently using this

```
<?php 

$transactions = $json1['result']['transactions'][0]['meta']['AffectedNodes'][0]['ModifiedNode']['FinalFields'];

foreach($transactions as $item){
    echo $item['account'];
}

?>
```

But this doesn't work, What I'm trying to echo is each transaction.

If you can see what I've done wrong that would be great thankyou; I am trying to get the [TX] info for each transaction.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use var_dump to see the varible type. Is $transactions an array? Is $item inside loop an array too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close but your inital variable assignment is too deep. You want to iterate over all of the transactions but you have assigned the whole first transaction to `$transactions` with the `[0]` (ie the first array element).

Try iterating over just the `transactions` key like below:

```
$transactions = $json1['result']['transactions'];
foreach($transactions as $transaction){
    $meta = $transaction['meta'];
    $tx = $transation['tx'];
    echo $tx['Account'];
}
```